# How do I run this ruby script again if this condition fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I built a Markov bot in Ruby for yuks and I'm setting up a local chron job to make it tweet four times a day. But my code's a bit slappy and noobish. The returned Markov tweets occasionally exceed 140 characters and if I'm running the script manually, that's fine. I have it set up to fail pleasantly. But if I'm going to automate this, I'd like to set it up so that if it fails because it exceeds the character count, I'd like it to try again until it succeeds. Here's my super basic if statement.

```
if tweet_text.size <= 140
    client.update( tweet_text )
    p "#{Time.now}: #{tweet_text}"
else
    p "Tweet exceeded 140 characters. Try again."
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood, you want to run this piece code everytime that the size of the tweet is superior to 140. I think that the easiest solution is to write it in a loop and exit the loop when the size is valid.

```
while true
    tweet_text = new_tweet # Change the text of tge tweet or the loo will loop forever
    if tweet_text.size <= 140
        client.update( tweet_text )
        p "#{Time.now}: #{tweet_text}"
        break
    else
        p "Tweet exceeded 140 characters. Try again."
    end
end
```

Hope it helped,

Gregory.

Comment: I had to tweak it a bit (I left some important code out of my example) but now it loops properly. If it breaks, it just loops back around and tries again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your loop will converge to a tweet shorter than 140, Gregory's answer is fine.

Otherwise, you might want to remove some substring if the tweet is too long :

```
if tweet_text.size <= 140
  client.update( tweet_text )
  p "#{Time.now}: #{tweet_text}"
else
  p "Tweet exceeded 140 characters. Truncating."
  truncated_tweet = tweet_text[0,69]+".."+tweet_text[-69,69]
  client.update( truncated_tweet )
  p "#{Time.now}: #{truncated_tweet}"
end
```